# Add more code to inherited event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have an inherited `jQuery` code where the `scroll` event has been set:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    // Whatever
});
```

Now I need to add some more functionality to the previous code when a click event is fired, but this new code must be removed when another element is clicked, something similar to the below code:

```
$('#element1').on('click', function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        // Add my code to the inherited one
    });
});


$('#element2').on('click', function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        // Unbind my code and leave the original behaviour
    });
});
```

However, I cannot rewrite the inherited code. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Try `$(window).off('scroll');`

Comment: @RayonDabre, if I do this the inherited code will not work anymore, and this is what I want to avoid. When I click one element I want to add my own code to the old one, and when I click the second element I want to keed only the old code

Comment: try use inside a method like "someMethod()",and try change function's reference to another function

Comment: @Genzotto, On `$('#element2')`, you must `off` the listener!

Comment: This `$('#element1').on('click', function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {` will put an arbitrary number of listeners to the scroll event on the stack, one on every click! You need to control by some means that not more than one listener is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [event.namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) to bind the event. then you can use [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove an event handler using *namespace*

```
$('#element1').on('click', function(){
    $(window).off('scroll.element').on('scroll.element', function(event) {
        // Add my code to the inherited one
    });
});

$('#element2').on('click', function(){
    $(window).off('scroll.element');
});
```

Using the above approach, default `scroll` event handler will have no impact.

Comment: Thak you so much, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Place all code inside function and use flag to execute as needed.

```
   var additionalCode = false;

   function usefulCode(event) {
       // here is your default code

       if (additionalCode) {
         // here is additional code
       }
    }

    $(window).on('scroll', usefulCode);

    $('#element1').on('click', function(){
        additionalCode = true;
    });

    $('#element2').on('click', function(){
        additionalCode = false;
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't it will bind both events on first function execution?

Comment: It's the same event. the outcome depends on additionalCode variable. I changed code a little.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding `scroll` event to `body` you can bind it to body specific class. Clicking button will swap classes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.body')
      .removeClass($(this).data('passive-class'))
      .addClass($(this).data('active-class'));
  });
});
```

```css
.origin {
  color: red;
}
.custom {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  Some content
  <button class="btn" data-active-class="origin" data-passive-class="custom">Scroll origin</button>
  <button class="btn" data-active-class="custom" data-passive-class="origin">Scroll custom</button>
</div>
```